# How can override formula by @attributeOverrride in hibernate 5.0

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Could you please let me know what are the way to override the '@formula' using '@AttributeOverrride' as like column

```
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="XX", column=@Column(name="XXX"),
    @AttributeOverride(name="X", column=@Column(name="XXXX"))
})
```

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more context?

Comment: In '@OneToMany'  using '@AttributeOverrides' ,there are way to override the column attribute of target entity. but under '@AttributeOverride' annotation it provide only two option 'name' and 'column' using these column mapping can be override for targetEntity.    Now in my case I am trying to override calculative property of target entity.

Comment: By my knowledge you can only override the mapping with existing table columns. I asked for a bit more context to maybe provide an alternative solution, without using the @AttributeOverrides annotation